# The way it's supposed to work with books in a team in InDesign is not coherent, then how to properly work?

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, book

Imagine this scenario:

- User A opens the book
- User B opens the book and make important changes
- User B saves the book
- User A closes the indesign and it's asked if wants to save the changes to the book
- Chooses YES

In this case all the changes of User B are lost!

But Indesign "tells us" to never open the document outside the book.

As you can see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6ccaa.html) they say the following: "Note: If you are sharing book files over a server, make sure that you have a file management system in place so that you don’t save over each other’s changes accidentally."

This is exactly my scenario;

They say "file management system" but how exactly to implement it for this case?
thanks

Comment: I don't use the book feature either, but I know that one is supposed to be able to use a single document in multiple book files, so I am confused about "not editing outside of the book"

Answer (score 1):

Having never worked with the book function in InDesign, I'm only guessing, but maybe this is your problem:

> Book files are separate from document files. For example, when you choose the Save Book command, InDesign saves the changes to the book, not the documents in the book.

Maybe what needs to happen is that User B has to save the *document* changes, rather than the *book* changes.

Comment: but then the document will not be included into the book

Comment: @Totty As I mentioned, I haven't used the book function. What happens if you edit the document outside the book?

Comment: well, it will be a warning in the book panel saying the book was opened outside the book. This makes me think that opening documents outside of the book is not good. Also it shows which documents are opened at the moment. But, from what I know the way to do, is to open the book and then open the documents.

Comment: @Totty It sounds like you need to run some tests and see what happens if you do open the document outside the book. In either case, if you don't save, your work is lost, so you should experiment with saving the document as well.

Comment: Basically the book gets nervous because it doesn't know if it needs to recalculate the page numbers. It's not a big deal really. It can sync back up and update the numbering later. I don't know of any other potential problem. /4 years of making books in InDesign.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: When I said to not save, it was relative to the Book, not the document. I already know what happens if I open a document outside the book and save it again: when I open the book panel again it will show a warning "This document was opened outside the book". And this seems something like this: "You've done something bad, or that was not supposed to be done."

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald: This is the only problem I might get if the document is saved outside the book? I don't need any of the features of the page numbering sync for the project I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: @totty It's just *warning* you that it was saved outside the book so that you know you have to update page numbering or whatever. That's why I suggested running a test. Make some test files that you can afford to have messed up, and play with them. *See what happens.* See if it's only the page numbering. See if the changes don't save. See if the file corrupts. Basically, take the risk and find out what happens if you don't obey InDesign's warning.